# iOS 14, lipo error while creating library for both device and simulator

Tags: xcodebuild, ios14, xcode12, lipo

We have been using lipo command to create a framework which works on both device and simulator when integrated in other project.
following are the build commands used to generate device and simulator builds

```
xcodebuild -target SampleSDK ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds"
xcodebuild -target SampleSDK ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds"
```

after this we are copying swift modules from iphonesimulator(if it exists) to the copied framework dir

```
cp -R "$BUILD_DIR/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PRODUCT_NAME}/Modules/SampleSDK.swiftmodule/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/"
```

and then lipo command

```
lipo -create "$BUILD_DIR/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PRODUCT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PRODUCT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}" -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PRODUCT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

the above command is failing with following error

```
fatal error: lipo: /path/to/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sample-bhfmlauxsdympmdjkjyvujaljevg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleSDK.framework/SampleSDK and /Users/rramshettysiddaraju/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sample-bhfmlauxsdympmdjkjyvujaljevg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SampleSDK.framework/SampleSDK have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

I tried one of the answers in stackoverflow, about adding user-defined setting VALID_ARCHS and then removing it. but that didnt work

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason for the error is that Xcode 12 includes a slice for the "arm64" architecture when building for the simulator (in addition to the usual "i386" and "x86_64" architectures for Xcode <12). This is probably for supporting the simulator on (future) Macs using Apple Silicon processors. As your device build also includes the "arm64" architecture, `lipo` does not know which of the two "arm64" slices you want and refuses to create a combined fat binary framework.

As a workaround, you can either exclude the "arm64" architecture from the simulator build by appending the `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` build variable:

```
xcodebuild -target SampleSDK ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds" EXCLUDED_ARCHS="arm64"
```

Alternatively, use `lipo -remove` to remove the "arm64" architecture from the simulator build before combining the simulator and device frameworks into one:

```
lipo -remove arm64 "$BUILD_DIR/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PRODUCT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}" -output "$BUILD_DIR/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PRODUCT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

In the long run, you might be better off building an [XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/), which should support devices and simulators without the need for using `lipo`. But I haven’t tested this yet.

Comment: Thanks styv, this helped and will also look into XCFramework

Comment: Thank god! Finally, I found this solution after 2 days for iOS 14.

Comment: Also do remove the `VALID_ARCHS` build setting in your project first, if you have any.

Answer (score 5):

styv is right.

You can also set Excluded Architectures in the Xcode Build Settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@xtyv's suggestion is spot on: using an XCFramework is the way to go.

Here is a Makefile to generate an XCFramework (apply substitutions and add other architectures accordingly to your scenario):

```
ARCHS = aarch64-apple-ios aarch64-apple-ios-sim
LIB = lib<library_name>.a
XCFRAMEWORK = <framework_name>-iOS.xcframework

all: $(XCFRAMEWORK)

.PHONY: $(ARCHS)
$(ARCHS): %:
    cargo build --target $@
    
$(XCFRAMEWORK): $(ARCHS)
    xcodebuild -create-xcframework  $(addprefix -library , $(foreach arch, $(ARCHS),$(wildcard target/$(arch)/debug/$(LIB)))) -headers <header_file> -output $@
```

Comment: Are you managing to build a rust framework that exposes / communicates with ObjC / Swift? I would love to be able to use UIKit from rust.

Answer (score 1):

### How to build this framework for devices

```bash
xcodebuild clean build \
  -project CodeToanBugUI.xcodeproj \
  -scheme CodeToanBugUI \
  -configuration Release \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -derivedDataPath derived_data \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

### Copy to the build folder

```bash
mkdir build/devices
cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/CodeToanBugUI.framework build/devices
```

### Build the framework for simulators

```bash
xcodebuild clean build \
  -project CodeToanBugUI.xcodeproj \
  -scheme CodeToanBugUI \
  -configuration Release \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -derivedDataPath derived_data \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64
```

### Copy to the build folder for simulators

```bash
mkdir build/simulator
cp -r derived_data/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ build/simulator/
```

### Create the universal framework

```bash
mkdir build/universal
cp -r build/devices/CodeToanBugUI.framework build/universal/
lipo -create \
  build/simulator/CodeToanBugUI.framework/CodeToanBugUI \
  build/devices/CodeToanBugUI.framework/CodeToanBugUI \
  -output build/universal/CodeToanBugUI.framework/CodeToanBugUI
```

### Copy the swiftmodule

```bash
cp -r build/simulator/CodeToanBugUI.framework/Modules/CodeToanBugUI.swiftmodule/* \
  build/universal/CodeToanBugUI.framework/Modules/CodeToanBugUI.swiftmodule/
```

### Create the xcodebuild -create-xcframework command

```bash
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
  -framework build/simulator/CodeToanBugUI.framework \
  -framework build/devices/CodeToanBugUI.framework \
  -output build/CodeToanBugUI.xcframework
```