# Appium Not Running Xcode 12.3

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I'm trying to use Appium version 1.19.1 to test an ipad app on a physical ipad device that I have built with Xcode 12.3. Previously this has worked as expected, but recently I have not been able to get Appium to run at all, and I suspect that Xcode 12.3 may be the issue based on what I have discovered.

When I try to run Appium from python this is the trace printed to my python console (device serial number/udid intentionally hidden):

```
    File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 155, in __init__
    proxy
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 225, in start_session
    response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
xcodebuild error message:

2021-01-06 17:04:24.366 xcodebuild[16217:213101] Error writing xctestrun file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “WebDriverAgentRunner_iphoneos14.3-arm64.xctestrun” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Build/Products/WebDriverAgentRunner_iphoneos14.3-arm64.xctestrun, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb116ac6ad0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
** TEST BUILD FAILED **
2021-01-06 17:04:24.380 xcodebuild[16217:213102]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-22--0600.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/WebDriverAgentRunner-E1E91CAE-6813-4009-872F-D9B73C898BBD/WebDriverAgentRunner-0D722399-E7A6-4474-8791-593FA62358F6/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021-01-06_170424-nMI8G0.log
2021-01-06 17:04:24.382 xcodebuild[16217:213028] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (DF79B2A2-04AF-4A59-87B7-DBB8279EC46E) Beginning test session WebDriverAgentRunner-DF79B2A2-04AF-4A59-87B7-DBB8279EC46E at 2021-01-06 17:04:24.381 with Xcode 12C33 on target <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fb11a157e10), ****, iPad, 14.3 (18C66), ****> {
        deviceSerialNumber:         ****
        identifier:                 ****
        deviceClass:                iPad
        deviceName:                 ****
        deviceIdentifier:           ****
        productVersion:             14.3
        buildVersion:               18C66
        deviceSoftwareVersion:      14.3 (18C66)
        deviceArchitecture:         arm64e
        deviceTotalCapacity:        249024532480
        deviceAvailableCapacity:    240144109568
        deviceIsTransient:          NO
        ignored:                    NO
        deviceIsBusy:               NO
        deviceIsPaired:             YES
        deviceIsActivated:          YES
        deviceActivationState:      Activated
        isPasscodeLocked:           NO
        deviceType:                 <DVTDeviceType:0x7fb113d0a3d0 Xcode.DeviceType.iPhone>
        supportedDeviceFamilies:    (
    1,
    2
)
        applications:              (null)
        provisioningProfiles:      (null)
        hasInternalSupport:        NO
        hasWritableSystem:         NO
        isSupportedOS:             YES
        bootArgs:                  (null)
        nextBootArgs:              (null)
        connected:                 YES
        isWirelessEnabled:         NO
        connectionType:            direct
        hostname:                  (null)
        bonjourServiceName:        ****
        activeProxiedDevice:       (null)
        } (14.3 (18C66))
2021-01-06 17:04:24.498 xcodebuild[16217:213028] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (****) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
*** If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-22--0600.xcresult
2021-01-06 17:04:24.514 xcodebuild[16217:213028] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.141 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2021-01-06 17:04:24.514 xcodebuild[16217:213028] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2021-01-06 17:04:24.514 xcodebuild[16217:213028] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.141 sec, +0.141 sec -- end
Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-22--0600.xcresult
Testing failed:
    Building for iOS, but the embedded framework 'CocoaAsyncSocket.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
    Building for iOS, but the embedded framework 'YYCache.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
    Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'CocoaAsyncSocket.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
    Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'YYCache.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
    WebDriverAgentRunner:
        WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-22--0600.xcresult. (Underlying Error: The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory)))
** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
Testing started. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
```

Through researching I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315026/1489990) which linked to [an apple developer forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669411?answerId=652663022#652663022) that leads me to believe the issue is with one of the frameworks that appium must be using that is not cooperating with Xcode 12.3.

I have also come across [another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/1489990) that I tried but it did not fix my issue.

Also, this is what I'm seeing in `Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-19--0600.xcresult`:

```
  Assertions: System: Failed to install or launch the test runner. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2021.01.06_17-04-19--0600.xcresult. (Underlying Error: The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory))
```

So is there anything else I can try at this point, or is this going to come down to a framework being used by appium needing to be updated? Any ideas or suggestions are definitely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to follow [the suggestion in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/1489990) *but* on the WebDriverAgent Xcode project. Seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After the installation WDA on real device, worked for me on appium 1.20 such workaround:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData 
$ rm -rf WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp 
$ mv WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp
```