# building for ios simulator, but the linked and embedded framework .framework' was built for ios

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I make universal frame only in iOS  but I am getting above error while run in Simulator.
building for ios simulator, but the linked and embedded framework .framework' was built for ios.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12.3: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework was built for iOS + iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303304/xcode-12-3-building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-and-embedded-framework-wa)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your framework's target contains the Supported platforms of both `iphonesimulator` (for Simulator) and `iphoneos` (for devices), in `Build Settings > Architecture`

Here's an example:
[image: Example]

Comment: I checked It contains both

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set VALID_ARCHS

Add new user defined variable in:

> Build Phase > User defined

And add different Arc in **Debug** and **Release**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with set **Debug** and **Release** value:

[Build Active Architecture only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ADz.png)