# Xcode 13 - Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework '****.framework' was built for iOS

Tags: frameworks, simulator, xcode13

Very similar questions but *Validate workspace* is no longer available in XCode 13.

[building for ios simulator, but the linked and embedded framework .framework' was built for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416827/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-and-embedded-framework-framework-wa)

[Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework '****.framework' was built for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267897/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-framework-framework-was-built)

Is there any other solution to this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is indeed an option to validate workspace under 'Build Options' but you have to select *All* to see the option.

[Validate workspace in Xcode 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VeAc.png)

Comment: I'm not able to see that option on my project, I'm using Xcode 14.0.1